Definition of the Principal Bundle for smooth manifolds?
The fiber bundle is defined as

A fiber bundle is defined as the tuple $(E, B, \pi)$ where $\pi: E \to B$ is a continuous surjective map from topological space $E$ to topological space $B$. Furthermore, there is a topological space $F$, called the fiber, such that for each $b\in B$ there is an open neighborhood $U\subset B$ with $b\in U$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)\subset E$ is homeomorphic to $B\times F$ via homeomorphism $\varphi: \pi^{-1}(U)\to B\times F$ and $\text{proj}_1\circ \varphi = \pi$.

$\pi^{-1}(\{b\}) \subset E$ is called the fiber of $b$.
One definition of a principal bundle is

The tuple $(E, B, \pi)$ is a $G$-principal bundle if it is a fiber bundle and if there is a continuous action $\lhd:E\times G \to E$ which preserves the fibers in $E$ (that is $x\in \pi^{-1}(b)$ then $x \lhd g \in \pi^{-1}(b)$ for $g\in G$) and which acts freely and transitively on the fibers in $E$.

But another definition or property I've seen for principal bundles over smooth manifolds is (e.g. in the Schuller lectures)

The tuple $(E, B, \pi)$ is a $G$-principal bundle if there is a smooth free action $\lhd: E\times G \to G$ and $\pi:E\to B$ is isomorphic as a smooth bundle to $\rho: E\to E/G$ where $\rho$ is the normal equivalence relation projection map where $\rho(e)$ for $e\in E$ maps $e$ to $[e]$, the equivalence class of $e$.

Since $\pi:E\to B$ is a smooth bundle then $E$ and $B$ are manifolds, $\pi$ is a smooth map, and $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to B\times F$ is a diffeomorphism.
Wikipedia also says that similar properties fully characterize the principal bundle.
Here are my questions.

Is there any reason the second principal bundle definition can't be relaxed to topological fiber bundles instead of smooth fiber bundles?
If the second principal bundle definition can and is weakened to be for topological fiber bundles then are the two definitions equivalent?
If the first principal bundle definition is strengthened to apply to smooth manifolds then are the two definitions equivalent?


What kind of group is $G$? For definition 1 to be correct as it stands, you need to assume something on the order of "$G$ is a compact Lie group and $E$ a manifold," see this answer. For definition 2, you'll also at least need that $G$ is a compact Lie group. If you want $G$ to be something more general (I guess the most general you can go is "arbitrary Lie group"), or $E$ in definition 1, then you'll need to add conditions.

Ah, sorry, the fiber is what needs to be a manifold in definition 1.

My suggestion is to avoid using Schuller's lectures as a source for learning anything. Wikipedia is also suboptimal. There are many textbooks covering this material.

@BenSteffan I guess for the first definition I would just say $G$ is a topological group so that "continuous" makes sense. For the second definition I would say $G$ is a Lie group so that the group action being smooth makes sense. You're suggesting these definitions aren't restrictive enough?

@MoisheKohan I've found the Schuller lectures to be very good and useful for a lot of topics. However, when it comes to bundles specifically, it seem that he uses some non-standard definitions which have led to a lot of confusion (lots of questions on this site and responses by you saying the lectures are a bad source). Would you mind pointing me towards a few good references where I can learn about Principal bundles?

There generally seems to be a lot of confusion online about the definition of Principal bundle which is very frustrating. I'm not sure if the literature/textbook references are better or not.

Steenrod's book, or Kobayashi-Nomizu . I wrote several answers on MSE dealing with terminological confusion regarding fiber bundles, I will try to locate these.

@Jagerber48 Yes. If you want to define something that matches the usual definitions of principal $G$-bundles people use and avoids pathologies, then you'll need to add more conditions, in particular something like properness of the action. Your frustration is entirely understandable; there are a sizeable number of competing definitions out there and a not insubstantial amount of them are "wrong" in more or less subtle ways.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399035/equivalence-of-definitions-of-principal-g-bundle/2135581#2135581

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560371/orbit-space-of-a-free-proper-g-action-principal-bundle/1754706#1754706

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A84907+fiber+bundle

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095741/doubt-in-the-definition-of-principal-bundle/3099251#3099251

Thank you very much for hunting down all those answers and references! It seems very complicated :(. I wish there was one place I could look to get a succinct definition of Principal bundle. Instead it feels like I need to learn 4 different definitions and all of the machinery to compare between the different definitions which is a much larger task than just digesting one definition.

@MoisheKohan I've asked a question looking for help on understanding the Kobayashi Nomizu definition of principal bundle here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4891961/understanding-the-definition-of-principal-bundle-kobayashi-and-nomizu it's similar to one of your linked answers, but I think my questions are really just very basic, coming from someone  who's still an "immature" reader of topological details.
